# checkout step 3 shipping method blank?

Tags: shipping

Im currently on magento 1.7 and when I try to checkout after filling out all the information i get stuck at step 3 for shipping method, it just shows up blank. I've been to system/config and made sure i have a shipping method on but it just doesn't show up?

Comment: Any errors in magento logs or php/apache logs? Any errors in javascript? Did you install 3rd party shipping extensions?

Comment: Have you enable shipping method from backend ?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you don't have any carriers switched on, or any that are returning rates. Suggest just switch on flat rate and see if that shows. If you have a custom checkout switch back to the default theme and see if it works there (if it does its a checkout issue).

If someone was totally failing you would see an exception in var/error.log. And it would probably bounce you back to the cart page which it isn't.